# Failure: ImportError (No module named 'bunch')

Tags: python, python-3.4, nose

I'm trying to run some python tests with the below command:

```
nosetests -e --process-timeout=1200 mytests.functional.test_1234
```

When I do I get this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named 'bunch')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/nose-1.3.7/build/lib/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/nose-1.3.7/build/lib/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/nose-1.3.7/build/lib/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/nose-1.3.7/build/lib/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 245, in load_module
    return load_package(name, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 217, in load_package
    return methods.load()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1220, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/me/git/python-test/mytests/functional/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bunch
ImportError: No module named 'bunch'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I tried running `sudo pip install bunch` but got this:

```
Collecting bunch
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/bunch/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:600) - skipping
```

Next I attempted to install bunch through PyCharm which seems to have succeeded but when I run `pip show bunch`, nothing is returned.

Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just add pypi.python.org as a trusted host on pip install. Try:

```
sudo pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org bunch
```